# Square of a tensor

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, conventions

I think,

$$\sigma_{ij}\sigma^{ij} = \sigma^2.$$

However,
on the Wikipedia page on [Raychaudhuri equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation),
It was mentioned:

$$\sigma^2=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{ij}\sigma_{ij}$$

I am confused, but I think the first equation is only valid for tensors whose inverse is the same as the tensor itself. Which is the correct one?

Also, IF (and only if),

$$\sigma_{ij}\sigma^{ij}= \sigma^2,$$ then is this true:

$$\sigma_{ij}\sigma_{ij}=\sigma^2 ~?$$

Please explain in detail.

Comment: I am starting to feel from the past questions you have asked on this site that you should perhaps start by studying special relativity (rather than general relativity) using tensors so you can get really comfortable with them. (Note that this is a friendly suggestion, not an attack.)

Comment: @Hunter, I've done some special relativity, But I agree Im not as comfortable with tensors as I should be.That is precisely why I joined the site, as I have no one here to help me out. Also, at 14, they dont take me seriously. Can you suggest some online references?

Comment: epx.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/~yhitoshi/particleweb/ptest-1.pdf might help you.

Comment: I strongly recommend [*Spacetime and Geometry*](http://www.amazon.com/Spacetime-Geometry-Introduction-General-Relativity/dp/0805387323) by Sean Caroll.

Comment: Thanx @Hunter They are quite good.....

Comment: Thanx @Wouter, They are quite good

Answer (score 1):

Properly you can only contract upper indices with lower indices, never two indices of the same type. Now $\sigma_{ij}$ is a tensor with two down indices, so it acts like $\sigma_{ij} x^j = y_i$, when contracted with a vector (up index) it produces a one-form (down index). Since you can only contract upper indices with down indices the notation $\sigma^2$ does not mean $\sigma_{ij}$ applied twice as if $\sigma$ were a matrix. Rather $\sigma^2$ denotes a scalar that is like the magnitude of a vector. It is the generalization of how if $p^j$ is a vector, $$p^2 := p^j p_j$$
where the $:=$ means "is defined as".
Sometimes a constant is included, so that $$\sigma^2 := k \sigma^{ij} \sigma_{ij}.$$

Comment: Right...But does the constant depend on some other constraint or no of dimensions or something like that?

Comment: And which is the correct one @Robin Ekman?

Comment: It's a definition. Any constant is correct. If writing, you should make it clear to the reader what constant you are using, and if reading, you should check to see what the author is using.

Comment: but then why is it specifically 1/2 in this case?